# Must had vs must have

Tags: word-choice, tenses, modal-verbs

If someone says that they had been to Florida on a recent trip, which one of the following would be a correct respone:

> - That must had been fun.
> - That must have been fun.

Or is there a better way of saying this?

Comment: The correct answer is *must have*. This is a very basic fact of English grammar, so unless you can give some specific indication of what's confusing you, this will be closed as "general reference".

Comment: @JSBᾶngs: I know it's simple but there are differences when it comes to imaginary situation, past habitual situation, and future predication. I don't know which one goes where. I am the guy who is lost in tenses.

Answer (score 8):

After modal auxiliary verbs like *must*, you use the plain form of the verb. But *had* is the past tense/participle form, so it can't go here. Only *must have* is correct.

Comment: What would we use if we were talking about an imaginary and future situations?

Comment: Even if talks about the past past? Pearl Sugars knew that her daughter was mentally unstable, if not unbalanced, and that she had gone off medication at eighteen. She must have known, as well, that pregnancy and the responsibility of child-rearing would stress my fragile mother to the breaking point.

Comment: Yes, the perfect gives it its past meaning, but the perfect needs to be formed with the plain form of "have".